# Can Jquery parse an audio podcast feed to HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, rss

I have found several ways of pulling blog feeds with jQuery, however are for text blogs not an audio pod-cast. I am really struggling in learning jQuery (self taught). I have also found ways of parsing to XML but I haven't found a Non flash based pod-cast player that parses HTML5. Adding the mp3's to the web page itself is redundant and beyond the technical expertise of the client.

It needs to dynamically update as the new pod-casts are added and it needs to have access to every pod cast that has been posted on this feed.

Please help me. What would the code look like to do this. Or are there any tutorials to teach me how to create this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery actually, but it does speed things up using it's built-in XML parser.

[`<audio>`](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/) tags use several different formats, depending on the browser. For cross-compatibility, you'd need to have all 3 formats to make make the tag work, but minimally, you'd need only ogg and mp3.

For a playlist, you can have an array of urls for your audio sources. For this, you'd need a 3d structure.

For example, a 3d array-object structure:

```
var sources = [
    { //audio 1
        'mp3':...,
        'ogg':...,
        'wav':...
    },
    { //audio 2
        'mp3':...,
        'ogg':...,
        'wav':...
    },
    ...
];
```

Since sources is an array, you can use `array.push()` to append a new item, or `array.unshift()` to prepend an item:

```
//add to the end of the array
sources.push({ 
    'mp3':...,
    'ogg':...,
    'wav':...
});

//add to beginning of array
sources.unshift({ 
    'mp3':...,
    'ogg':...,
    'wav':...
});
```

Comment: how do I get the one url to create the 3 array files?

Comment: @skids89 you only need one array that contains 3 urls per item, each pointing to a different format of the item. This is created on the server side.

Comment: Ah got it! Can a new array be dynamically added for each new episode?

Comment: if you meant adding a new item (an additional 3 urls) to the list, yes.

Comment: Could you edit your post to show how that works also, please and thank you.

Comment: whats the best way to learn the full code I would need to implement this?